# Does Devastator have a weak spot?

Tags: transformers

There are two times in Transformers G1 when Devastator is taken back to pieces by firing a single shot at him. Once is when Optimus Prime aims carefully at him when Devastator is distracted by a hologram of a giant Autobot created by Hound. And the other is in the episode Carnage in C-Minor where Perceptor aims his lens to him and fires a precise shot at some part of him which isn’t seen clearly due to the distance.

All the other times, the Autobots and sometimes even the Decepticons fire barrages of lasers at him and nothing happens. I wonder if the comics gave some further explanation about this.

Does Devastator have a weak spot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### He apparently has *several* weak spots.

According to his bio in *[Hasbro Transformers Collectors' Club #42](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Hasbro_Transformers_Collectors%27_Club_issue_42)* (December, 2011), Devastator was hastily constructed under less-than-ideal conditions, as a result of which, the bonds between the individual Transformers he's composed of are weaker than those of his predecessor, Bruticus, making it possible to disassemble him if enough force is directed at the proper targets. The precise location of these targets was not specified.

> WEAKNESSES
>
> Devastator was constructed using borrowed technology and with considerable haste. For these reasons, the bond between the individual minds from which he is composed is not as strong as that of his predecessor, Bruticus. Enough force aimed at the proper targets could cause the giant to disassemble into his six components.
>
> [image]